# How to insert ta column of random numbers to the existing text file

Tags: shell-script

You can see below there is file "sample.txt", here I want to insert a 2nd column with random numbers(5 digits) and 3rd column with date(yyyy-mm-dd). Please help

[image]

Comment: Today’s date? Random dates?

Comment: How to delimit the columns?

Comment: We're not really a script-writing service. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please [DO NOT post screenshots of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Answer (score 2):

**`paste`** + **`shuf`** + **`head`** solution:

```
paste yourfile <(shuf -i 0-100 -n 5) <(yes $(date +"%Y-%m-%d") | head -n5)
```

Sample output:

```
1   35  2018-01-16
2   16  2018-01-16
3   52  2018-01-16
4   72  2018-01-16
5   68  2018-01-16
```

Comment: Thanks for your timely help. But, I need to insert the random dates. Could you please tell, how??

Answer (score 0):

To add data to your existing text file ,use text editors provided in linux like:-

- [Geidt](https://help.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/)
- [Pluma](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjC6-aoq9zYAhWEvrwKHTzmB-sQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FPluma_(editor)&usg=AOvVaw3ZdyPXtt57lDIcSVTK8eRw)
- vi editor
- nano

Gedit and Pluma are GUI based editors whereas vi editor and nano are lightweight editors (terminal based).

To get more details about vi editor and nano use **man** command.

Usage-->
man [name of the editor without brackets]

Comment: this would be a rough job if one would have a file with 1 million lines for example

Comment: I agree @mazs but my answer is based solely on the problem mentioned above.With increasing complexity one can even switch to file handling techniques provided by various programming languages.